# No module named "Urllib2" for mixpanel-api

Tags: python, export-to-csv, mixpanel

I am trying to export my mixpanel data to a csv file. I installed the mixpanel API. Post that, I ran the code but am getting the error No module named "Urllib2".
I tried searching on the net on how to install the module, but couldn't figure out anything. Apparently, it isn't used anymore.
In such a case, what can I do, since Urllib2 is a part of mixpanel API, I'm assuming.

Attaching the screenshot with the code and error here.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

from the given screen, it looks like you are using Python 2. I would recommend using Python 3. -- https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-utils

To install this, you will need to navigate to your machine's terminal and enter the following command:

```
pip install mixpanel-utils
```

From there, we would need a Python script that looks something like this:
To use the mixpanel_utils module import it like so:

```
from mixpanel_utils import MixpanelUtils
```

Then create a new Mixpanel object like:

```
mputils = MixpanelUtils(
'Service Account Secret',
service_account_username='Service Account Username',
project_id='Project ID',
token='Project Token',
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).